# C# + Unity - Getting the MIN value from a variables inside a List of Classes

Tags: c#, list, class, unity-game-engine

I have a list of this Class:

```
public class EachEnemy
{
    public GameObject enemy;
    public Vector3 coords;
    public float distance;

}
```

And they calculate the 'distance' to a Ship.
As the enemies spawn and move, the distance variables changes all the time.

I need to find which is the smallest of those distances inside the List of that Class, and its index so I can target the Enemy object.

Comment: https://morelinq.github.io/1.x/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MinBy__2_1.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) like

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Wherever you get this from
List<EachEnemy> allEnemies;

// Sorted by the distance to this object
var sortedEnemies = allEnemies.OrderBy(enemy => (transform.position - enemy.coords).sqrMagnitude);
// Or depending on how your class is used simply
//var sortedEnemies = allEnemies.OrderBy(enemy => enemy.distance);

// This would return null if the list was empty
// Or the first element of the sorted lost -> smallest distance  
var nearestEnemy = sortedEnemies.FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that using

```
OrderBy(enemy => (transform.position - enemy.coords).sqrMagnitude);
```

Would be more efficient than actual calculating the distances first since it skips using a square root on all the vector `sqrMagnitude`s. Since `a > b` also implies `a² > b²` and we know that a magnitude is always positive it is enough to know the `sqrMagnitude`s of all the delta vectors in order to sort them.

The advantage of this would be that you can also get the second and third closest enemies etc.

Comment: Nonetheless, implementing O(n log n) when O(n) would do makes no sense. The data doesn't need to be sorted; the OP just wants the item with the smallest value, which can be found in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

You can go over each item in the list and save value outside the loop, and also save the index outside the loop, e.g.

```
EachEnemy someFuncname(List<EachEnemy> list) 
{
    int index = 0;
    EachEnemy ea = null;
    float distance = 9999 ///
    
    foreach (var Enemy in list) {
        if (Enemy.Distance < distance) {
            ea = Enemy;
    }
    return ea;
}
```

You can also return the index in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
float smallestDistance = eachEnemyList[0].distance;

    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < eachEnemyList.Count; i++)
    {
        if(eachEnemyList[i].distance < smallestDistance)
        {
            smallestDistance = eachEnemyList[i].distance;

            index = i;
        }
    }
```

This is probably not perfectly optimized but should do just fine. This gives you both the smallest distance and the index of the EachEnemy class containing the smallest distance.